# Form se cierra automaticamente una vez llamado del program.cs

Tags: c#

mi duda consiste en lo siguiente...
En el Program.cs de mi aplicacion llamo a otro form para que se abra, pero este se cierra automáticamente... este es mi codigo

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        UpdateProcess();
    }
    static void UpdateProcess()
    {
        //Get latest and current versions code

        if (cv >= lv)
        {
            Application.Run(new SupremePicker());
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Carga bien el else");
            FormPop i = new FormPop();
            i.Show();
            MessageBox.Show("Comando para abrir form enviado");
            //Cuando hago click en este ultimo messagebox mi app se cierra.
        }
    }
```

Dejo el codigo de mi FormPopout aqui por si alguien es tan amable de ayudarme

```
public FormPop()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(rutademiupdater.exe);
    Application.Exit();
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SupremePicker.SupremePicker principal = new SupremePicker.SupremePicker();
    principal.Show();
    Close();
}
```

Comment: y donde esta el otro formulario que se abrio previamente? que seria el principal que mantiene la app abierta?

Comment: No quiero mostrar ese formPrincipal ya que necesito que abra un PopOut antes que el formPrincipal y una vez confirmada la operacion en el formPopOut quiero que se muestre el formPrincipal... como hago para que no se cierre el formPrincipal, pero que tampoco se muestre hasta que la confirmacion lo permita?

Comment: Nose si me explique bien asi que lo escribo de otra forma... tengo 2 forms, uno llamado formPrincipal otro formPopout. en Program.cs quiero que muestre el formPopout primero, luego en el formPopout tengo 2 botones uno si otro no, el no abre el formPrincipal y el si realiza el proceso de actualización...

Comment: claro pero este codigo no hace eso ni de casualidad.. cuando se cierra tu popup, que esperas que haga tu programa? porque cuando se cierra, no hace nada mas...

Comment: No espero que mi Popout se cierre... espero que al clickear si o no se abra formPrincipal o se ejecute la actualizacion... por eso necesito ayuda y estoy aqui...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que necesitas, hacer es arrancar el `form1` y abrir un formulario en modo `Dialog`

Cuando carga el formuladio en el evento Load, primero abres tu formulario en Modo Dialog, y hasta que este no se cierre ejecutando la logica que necesites, no te permitira ver otras ventanas.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Carga bien el else");
        FormPop i = new FormPop();
        i.ShowDialog();
    }
```

En la propiedades del formulario podes quitarles los botones, de minimizar, resturar y cerrar para evitar que la cierren por ese lado.

Comment: Me optimizaste un monton de codigo gracias, pero ahora me surgio otro problema... quiero que al oprimir NO en el FormPop este se cierre y se abra FormPrincipal... si pudieras ayudarme estare muy agradecido

Comment: El tema es que estoy instanciando el FormPop en program.cs y nose como cerrarlo desde FormPop

Comment: Si te sirvio marca la pregunta como correcta. Deberias, usar this.Close(), dentro del formulario que queres cerrar.

Comment: Deberias primero abrir el form principal y seguido abris el pop, luego de usar el pop lo cerras y queda abierto el form principal

Comment: Eso hago, pero cuando pongo this.Close(); se cierra tambien el FormPrincipal que instancie previamente para que se muestre...

Comment: fijate el this.Close(), que este sobre el formulario Pop y no el principal

Comment: este es mi boton el FormPop ```        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SupremePicker.SupremePicker formPrincipal = new SupremePicker.SupremePicker();
            formPrincipal.Visible = true;
            formPrincipal.Enabled = true;
            formPrincipal.Opacity = 100;
            formPrincipal.Show();
            formPrincipal.Focus();
            this.Close();
  
        }```

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106449/discussion-between-ramiro-barone-and-gby).